# assembly language: why is my code showing incorrect output?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I am writing a program in assembly language (x86).  I simply want to print the character '9' to the screen by pulling data from an array.  Here is the code:

```
.model  tiny
.stack  100h
.data   
hex     db  39h,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

.code
.startup
        lea di,hex
        mov dl,[di]
        mov ah,2
        int 21h    
.exit
end
```

I am trying to grab the very first byte of the "hex" array and print it out, which should display '9'.  However it doesn't appear to be printing anything.

Comment: looks like MASM, not NASM.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct.  I will update.

Comment: Are you assembling this with an assembler that produces 16-bit DOS programs?

Comment: It's been a **long** time since I've written PC assembly, but do you need something at the end (e.g., an "exit" syscall)? Otherwise, the program may just continue to execute random bytes...

Comment: @MikeHarris Most older assemblers will emit the required exit code with the the `.exit` macro. likely if this is compiled to an EXE `.exit` would translate to something like int 21h/ah=4c

Comment: You probably need to set up `DS`. Learn to use a debugger. Oh, and avoid 16 bit DOS code if possible :)

Comment: @MichaelPetch, yes, I'm using MASM for 16bit DOS console programs.

Comment: Along the lines of Jester, I'm curious if it works if you replace `.model tiny` with `.model small`

Comment: If compiled to a COM file, you can just `ret` from your entry point to close the program. I assume the assembler will do that using the `.exit` macro, too. I can't imagine why a small model would work when a tiny model wouldn't. Tiny puts code and data in the *same* segment, which should be precisely what you want here.

Comment: @CodyGray : Unfortunately many of the old compilers would allow you to specify a tiny model and produce an EXE from it. If the target is a COM program it should work, but if they generated an EXE file it won't. Additionally with tiny model you don't specify a stack (which they did here) leading me to believe they likely generated an EXE rather than COM. WOuld also explain why the code didn't work for them. My idea to switch from tiny to small was assuming an EXE and the `.startup` macro would generate the required DS and SS initialization code. `.startup` with tiny doesn't emit such code.